# Tcl/tk - Multiple font colors in same text box

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

Is it possible to have multi font colors within same text box.
The following code turns the entire text in the text widget to yellow:

```
.t.configure -fg yellow
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to have multiple colours in the same text widget, you have to specify which characters have those colours. You do this by putting a *tag* on those characters. You can configure the tag to use a different foreground colour, among other various properties (you can also change the background, the font, the indentation rules, etc.)

The simplest time to add a tag is when you're inserting the text:

```
pack [text .t]
.t insert 1.0 "this is red\n" tag1 "this is blue\n" tag2
.t tag configure tag1 -foreground red
.t tag configure tag2 -foreground blue
```

There are other subcommands of the `tag` method to let you alter where tags are applied.